# Right spaces in varchar type

Tags: mysql

I have 2 rows in table,

```
field
-----
A 
A //and space
```

That is `A` and `A` with right space, column type is `VARCHAR(3)`,

This query

```
  SELECT field FROM `table` WHERE field = 'A'
```

returns both rows,

Question: Why returned row `A` with right space also?

Comment: It's always a good idea to search [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html) first. You can find interesting things there, like [this one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html), maybe (just an example).

Comment: apologies for misunderstanding the `why` with `how` in the question. Answer removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character equality comparisons in MySQL are performed without regard to trailing spaces. If you want trailing spaces considered, you can use the `LIKE` operator.

Read this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html